# Converting a die-roll "equation" into an average result?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a spreadsheet to figure out the damage output of various Pathfinder 2e builds. I've got most of it down, but I want to figure out a way to convert a damage-roll equation (e.g "1d8+5+2d6") into an its average result (e.g "16.5").

I figure splitting the equation in question into its individual components and then adding them back together is pretty easy (it should just be a =SPLIT function followed by a =SUM function). The hard part is converting the die-rolls themselves into averages, because I need some way for google docs to convert the string "XdY" into ((Y/2) + 0.5) * X.

Is there an easy way to do this without needing to chain variables across multiple cells? Ideally I'd like one formula that takes the damage-roll equation as an input and spits the average out as an output.

Comment: While I can't answer your question I do see a simplification:  You don't need to address all XdY cases.  Rather, replace dY with "* (Y+1)/2.  That gets it down to 5 values which might very well be practical to do by table lookup.

Comment: That is not big problem but with your explanation, this `1d8+5+2d6` average do not match your desired output `16.5`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your dice-rolling equation in A1 you can try:

```
=arrayformula(let(
splitarray,split(transpose(split(A1,"+")),"d"),
padwith1s,if(splitarray,splitarray,1),
sum(choosecols(padwith1s,1)*((choosecols(padwith1s,2)/2)+0.5))))
```

N.B. this formula effectively treats constants as a 1-sided die (e.g. your '5' is evaluated as if it were '5d1'). This simplifies the evaluation of the array as the same operation can then be done on each row - mathematically the result is identical (as (1/2)+0.5=1).